# $\iint \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \, dy \, dx $ over the region $\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R^2}\mid x \le x^2+y^2\le2x\}$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Calculate $\iint \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \, dy \, dx $ over the region $\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R^2}\mid x \le x^2+y^2\le2x\}$

I will state here how I attempted at solving it. First I converted it to polar coordinate system. So my new integration became $\iint r^2 \, d\theta \, dr$. And I realize that the region is given by two circles as shown here http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?t=crmtb01&f=ob&i=x%20%5Cle%20x%5E2%2By%5E2%5Cle2x
But I don't know how to convert the region into polar form. 
Please help me out with that. 
I realize that my region is $x \le x^2+y^2\le2x\implies \cos\theta\le r\le2\cos\theta$. But I don't know what to do after that.

If possible please suggest me a webpage where I can practice more of these.

Answer (score 3):

You already got the bounds on $r$, i.e. $\cos \theta \le r \le 2\cos \theta$. So, you just need the bounds for $\theta$.

The inequality $\cos \theta \le r \le 2\cos \theta$ holds for some value of $r$ if and only if $\cos \theta \le 2 \cos \theta$, i.e. $\cos \theta \ge 0$. Hence, the bounds on $\theta$ are $-\dfrac{\pi}{2} \le \theta \le \dfrac{\pi}{2}$.

This gives you the double integral $\displaystyle\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\int_{\cos \theta}^{2\cos \theta}r^2\,dr\,d\theta$.

Now simply evaluate this to get the answer.

Comment: It might be mentioned that this is _exactly twice_ the area between the two curves, as would be found by a polar area integration.  This suggests a direct way to obtain the value without doing any actual integration...

Comment: Any book or online resource where I can practice more of these?

Comment: Are you looking for more problems on double integration generally or on integration over areas defined by "polar" curves?